# Doctrine/dflydev - OneToMany associated ID

Tags: php, doctrine, silex

I got this error from my `UserRepository`:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 51 near 'h': Error: Class DokMngr\Entity\User has no association named id

I understand that the error comes from the missing declaration inside my user entity. I can not find a correct syntax when a field is both a generated id and a OneToMany association.

Hope somebody can help me to solve my problem or at least explain why I can't use an id as an association.

```
class UserRepository extends EntityRepository 
{
    public function findAllwithHistoryCount() {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->leftJoin('u.id', 'h');
        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
}

/**
 * @Entity(repositoryClass="DokMngr\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @Table(name="users")
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue
     */
    protected $id;
}

/**
 * @Entity(repositoryClass="DokMngr\Repository\HistoryRepository")
 * @Table(name="history")
 */
class History
{
    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="id")
     * @JoinColumn(name="user", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $user;
}
```

Comment: You seems to trying to join some `History` to your user, but the User don't know about `History` since the ManyToOne is unidirectional. In your User entity, you have no reference to the history. What result do you expect exactly?

Comment: @olibiaz For the beginning to join the table and show all columns.
How do I create this missing reference between `User.id` and `History.user`? `@OneToMany(targetEntity="History", mappedBy="user")` above my id declaration will be ignored.

Comment: If you want to refer the History from the User entity, you should use a bidirectionnal relation : http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional

Comment: @olibiaz Sure, but how if one of the two connected fields is the id?

Comment: Not sure to understand what you mean by "connected" and what problem you think that can happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Olibiaz I found my error in reasoning.
I thought the whole time that I have to create an association between `User.id` and `History.user` like inside the database.
But instead I have to create a new field `histories` in my `User` entity. (which exactly not exist inside the database)

So here's the corrected entities:

**User**

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @Entity(repositoryClass="DokMngr\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @Table(name="users")
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="History", mappedBy="user")
     */
    private $histories;
}
```

**History**

```
/**
 * @Entity(repositoryClass="DokMngr\Repository\HistoryRepository")
 * @Table(name="history")
 */
class History
{
    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="histories")
     * @JoinColumn(name="user", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $user;
}
```